# WP image link changes on permalink change

Tags: php, wordpress, image, apache, joomla

Migrated my joomla site to WP. The images were in a folder named 'asets' in joomla site. I copied the dir to wp and images work fine while url structure is raw.
But if I change the url permalink, the link to images also change.

```
like
sitename/?p=123 image path = sitename/asets/imagefile this works.

sitename/samplepost image path = sitename/post-name/asets/imagefile image not found

sitename/archive/123 image path = sitename/archive/asets/imagefile image not found

Please help me to solve this problem.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use absloute path or relative path with slash at start of path to get the root path.

I guss your HTML code look now like this:

```
<img src="assets/imagefile.jpg" alt="" />
```

So is it a relative path, the browser add the src to current url.
But if you change this to relative path from root it's will be work:

```
<img src="/assets/imagefile.jpg" alt="" />
```

Or using full absolute path:

```
<img src="http://example.com/assets/imagefile.jpg" alt="" />
```

[All about HTML file paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

More important thing, in wordpress you must to work only in theme directory scope And use [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) function.

Your code need to look like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/imagefile.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: @Jiban Note what I mentioned in the end, it's very important according to the rules of the WordPress codex.

Comment: Could not notice any difference, but I have done as you said. I have another question. Is there any way to display youtube video in wp comment? I found two plugins in net "FitVids for WordPress" and "oEmbed in Comments" but both do not work. Still the url showing.

Comment: Are you used the get_stylesheet_directory_uri() in a path?
All your code need to be under /wp-content/themes/yourthemename/

For the another question, Just paste youtube link as text in the editor, it's will be replaced by video immediately

Comment: Used the get_stylesheet. Pasting url in comment does not show video. It shows link only. I already have some youtube url in comments (posted in previous joomla site). Moreover I pasted some for test.

Comment: @Jiban, I don't see you talk about comments, sorry.

So, you need use a hook with filter and replace the link to an iframe.

`add_filter( 'pre_comment_content', '_convert_youtube_link_to_iframe', 10, 1 ); 
function _convert_youtube_link_to_iframe( $string ) {
 return preg_replace(
  "/\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu(be.com\/watch\?v=|.be\/)([a-zA-Z0-9\-h_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i",
  "<iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$2\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",
  $string
 );
}`

Add this code to functions.php